# C# compile error: "lc.exe" exited with code -1073741819

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors

Whenever I try to compile my C# project inside or outside of Visual Studio, I get this error:

```
"lc.exe" exited with code -1073741819
```

The executable `lc.exe` exists on my system under Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs.

I tried:

- Updating Visual Studio
- Cleaning and rebuilding the solution
- Removing then re-applying the project builds under Solution > Properties.

Nothing has helped. What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. In my case, there was a `licenses.licx` file in the Properties folder of the solution. I needed to find this file in Visual Studio, right-click, and Exclude from Project. (Note that deleting the file using file explorer did not work).

Then I was successfully able to rebuild the solution in Visual Studio or using the cmd line.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the issue today. In my case the workaround was to **run Visual Studio as administrator**.